# Replace part of a string (text mining)

Tags: r, text-mining

I would like to replace "Replace" part within strings from df$x to the first word of df$y column. I have a df like this:

```
x                 y
ABC-Replace-YUI   M46 Hello
CBD-Replace-TYU   MD5 Hello
DBE-Replace-RTY   M6 Hello
EBF-Replace-ERT   M79 Hello
FBG-Replace-WER   MMM8 Hello
```

And I would like to get the following data:

```
x               y
ABC-M46-YUI     M46 Hello
CBD-MD5-TYU     MD5 Hello
DBE-M6-RTY      M6 Hello
EBF-M79-ERT     M79 Hello
FBG-MMM8-WER    MMM8 Hello
```

Unfortunately, I have no experience in text mining and I need the most efficient way to do that as I have a huge dataset with similar substitutions for each row. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_replace` to replace the 'Replace' with the first word of each string in 'y' column (extracted with `word`)

```
library(stringr)
df1$x <- str_replace(df1$x, "Replace", word(df1$y,1))
df1$x
#[1] "ABC-M46-YUI"  "CBD-MD5-TYU"  "DBE-M6-RTY"   "EBF-M79-ERT"  "FBG-MMM8-WER"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c("ABC-Replace-YUI", "CBD-Replace-TYU", "DBE-Replace-RTY", 
"EBF-Replace-ERT", "FBG-Replace-WER"), y = c("M46 Hello", "MD5 Hello", 
"M6 Hello", "M79 Hello", "MMM8 Hello")), .Names = c("x", "y"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that **-Replace-** refers to the position rather than the excact words, therefore it is incorrect to substitute **Replace** itself, but to identify the **-content-** in this position and *replace* it.

```
 df1 <- data.frame(x = c("ABC-Replace-YUI", 
         "CBD-anything-TYU", "DBE-test-RTY", 
         "EBF-bad-ERT", "FBG-good-WER"), 
          y = c("M46 Hello", "MD5 Hello", 
                "M6 Hello", "M79 Hello", 
                "MMM8 Hello"))
                     x          y
    1  ABC-Replace-YUI  M46 Hello
    2 CBD-anything-TYU  MD5 Hello
    3     DBE-test-RTY   M6 Hello
    4      EBF-bad-ERT  M79 Hello
    5     FBG-good-WER MMM8 Hello
```

So you can replace the content between `-` and `-` with the first word in y.

```
library(stringr)
df1$x2 <- mapply(gsub,
                 "(?<=\\-).*?(?=\\-)", 
                 word(df1$y,1), df1$x, perl = T)

df1
                 x          y           x2
1  ABC-Replace-YUI  M46 Hello  ABC-M46-YUI
2 CBD-anything-TYU  MD5 Hello  CBD-MD5-TYU
3     DBE-test-RTY   M6 Hello   DBE-M6-RTY
4      EBF-bad-ERT  M79 Hello  EBF-M79-ERT
5     FBG-good-WER MMM8 Hello FBG-MMM8-WER
```

Comment: `I guess that -Replace- refers to the position rather than the excact words` - if this was true, OP would not have accepted akrun's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stri_extract_first_words` from `stringi` package to get the first word and then apply `sub` function in a vectorized way using `mapply`

```
library(stringi)
df1$x <- mapply(sub, "Replace", stri_extract_first_words(df1$y), df1$x, 
                                                                USE.NAMES = FALSE)

df1$x
#[1] "ABC-M46-YUI"  "CBD-MD5-TYU"  "DBE-M6-RTY"   "EBF-M79-ERT"  "FBG-MMM8-WER"
```